# Dividing up a .csv into dates, then writitng new csv files

Tags: r

I've been trying to divide a rather large data set up into separate .csv files based on dates. I have 60 rows per date, with 6 columns.

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
data<-read.csv("CB26_2019.csv", sep=",", header=T)
unique.dates<-unique(data$Date)
unique.dates<-unique.dates[1:(length(unique.dates))]
```

I haven't had much luck trying out methods, as I am relatively new to r. Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: The third line doesn't really make sense. You would be assigning a vector back to itself (unchanged). You can just use `split` to work with `data$Date` as the indexing vector. The `split` function will handle the "uniqueness" issue transparently.

Comment: You may also look at `group_split()` in `dplyr`

Comment: Consider adding the source .csv file to help people answering your question. Even if this is obvious to you, they might see something that would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you explained, here is a small reproducible example. In my fake data, I have 5 unique dates, each with 6 observations (unique "id") of "value".

This is a pretty common operation to do with base R `split`, `lapply`, and `write.csv`. You take your big *data.frame*, split it into a *list* of data.frames, then use `lapply` to iterate over the list elements. In my example `lapply` calls an "anonymous function" that takes a split data.frame as an argument, calculates what the file name needs to be, and writes the file with `write.csv`.

```r
# basic synthetic data: 5 days, with 6 values per day
data <- do.call('rbind', lapply(seq(as.Date("2019/01/01"), by = "day", length.out = 5),
                                function(x) return(data.frame(Date = rep(x, 6), id = 1:6, value = rnorm(6)))))

list_by_day <- split(data, data$Date)

# inspect 2nd element of 5
list_by_day[[2]]
#>          Date id       value
#> 7  2019-01-02  1 -0.98222379
#> 8  2019-01-02  2  0.08023993
#> 9  2019-01-02  3 -0.21896783
#> 10 2019-01-02  4  0.12009357
#> 11 2019-01-02  5 -0.55022410
#> 12 2019-01-02  6 -2.30440955
length(list_by_day)
#> [1] 5

lapply(list_by_day, function(x) {
  file_name <- sprintf("this_is_a_filename_%s.csv", unique(x$Date))
  write.csv(x, file = file_name)
})
#> $`2019-01-01`
#> NULL
#> 
#> $`2019-01-02`
#> NULL
#> 
#> $`2019-01-03`
#> NULL
#> 
#> $`2019-01-04`
#> NULL
#> 
#> $`2019-01-05`
#> NULL

list.files(".", "csv")
#> [1] "this_is_a_filename_2019-01-01.csv" "this_is_a_filename_2019-01-02.csv"
#> [3] "this_is_a_filename_2019-01-03.csv" "this_is_a_filename_2019-01-04.csv"
#> [5] "this_is_a_filename_2019-01-05.csv"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here a quick example. Split your dataframe by date; the dates will be the name of the files, so the / has to be replaced since otherwise an invalid path; feed the split dataframe to purrr's walk2.

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  date = c("01/01/2000", "02/01/2000", "03/01/2000"),
  value = c("a", "b", "c")
)

my_df %>% 
  split(.$date %>% str_replace_all(., "/", "_")) %>% 
  walk2(., names(.), .f=~write_csv2(., file=paste0(.y, ".csv")))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>